# How to redirect to another page and use props in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redirect

in route i set `props`:

```
<Route path="/getFilePage" exact component={GetFilePage} CourseName={props.CourseName} />
```

in main page i write this code for redirect:

```
return <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/getFilePage',
          CourseName:"C++"
       }}/>
```

in `GetFilePage` component i write in componentDidMount `console.log(this.props.location.CourseName)` but is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax is wrong. Try like below:

```
return <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/getFilePage',
          state:{CourseName:"C++"}
       }}/>
```

And take params like below:

```
this.props.location.state.CourseName
```

Comment: I did what you said but I got the "Cannot read property 'CourseName' of undefined" error

Answer (score 0):

Pass your props like this to the children:

```
<Route 
  path="/login" 
  render={(props) => <GetFilePage {...props} CourseName={props.CourseName}/>} 
/>
```

and props should be available at:

props.CourseName